# Random tick/check while checking my checkbox in Custom Listview

Tags: android, listview

While checking my checkbox in Custom Listview or even Scroll up or down the checking has been done for those Checkbox which i have not even clicked or touched. Here I'm attaching my `getView` method,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (transList != null) {
        final int pos = position;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.export_item_list, null);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.export_chk);
            txtOrdNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_exportOrdNo);
            txtOrdDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_exportDate);
            txtOrdStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_exportStatus);
            convertView.setTag(new OrdersViewHolder(checkBox, txtOrdNo,
                        txtOrdDate, txtOrdStatus));
            // checkbox click function
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        cb.setChecked(true);
                        // save item in preference
                        String itemName = transList.get(pos).getHhTran_referenceNumber();
                        supporter.saveOrderInPreference(itemName, 1);

                        //to check and uncheck selectAll checkbox
                        if(!selectAll.isChecked()) {

                            boolean selectCheck = true;
                            int c=exportItems.getChildCount();
                            for(int i=0; i<exportItems.getChildCount();i++) {
                                LinearLayout listViewLayout = (LinearLayout) exportItems.getChildAt(i);
                                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox) listViewLayout.findViewById(R.id.export_chk);
                                System.out.println("i="+i);
                                if(!chkBox.isChecked()) {
                                    selectCheck = false;
                                    System.out.println("i inside="+i);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                                if(selectCheck){
                                    selectAll.setChecked(true);
                                    supporter.setSelectAllCheckedForOrder();
                                }

                            }
                        } else {
                            cb.setChecked(false);
                            supporter.removeOrderFromPreference(transList.get(pos).getHhTran_referenceNumber());

                            //to check and uncheck selectAll checkbox
                            if(selectAll.isChecked()) {
                                selectAll.setChecked(false);
                                supporter.setSelectAllNotCheckedForOrder();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                boolean isExist = isOrderExist(transList.get(pos).getHhTran_referenceNumber());

                if (isExist) {
                    // set qty
                    // int qty =
                    // getMyItem(reciptList.get(pos).getHhReceipt_docnumber());
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                }

            } else {
                OrdersViewHolder viewHolder = (OrdersViewHolder) convertView
                        .getTag();
                checkBox = viewHolder.getCheckBox();
                txtOrdNo = viewHolder.getTxtOrdNo();
                txtOrdDate = viewHolder.getTxtOrdDate();
                txtOrdStatus = viewHolder.getTxtOrdStatus();
            }

            int day = transList.get(position).getHhTran_transDay();
            int month = transList.get(position).getHhTran_transMonth();
            int year = transList.get(position).getHhTran_transYear();
            String strDate = supporter.getStringDate(year, month, day);

            int stusVal = transList.get(position).getHhTran_status();
            System.out.println("Order Status:"+stusVal);
            String strStaus = "";
            if (stusVal == 0) {
                strStaus = "New";
            } else {
                strStaus = "Exported";
            }
          txtOrdNo.setText(transList.get(position).getHhTran_referenceNumber());
            txtOrdDate.setText(strDate);
            txtOrdStatus.setText(strStaus);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Please help me out to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `checked` status only in the `convertView == null` branch. You're not setting it in the `else` branch, so the checked status of a recycled checkbox is retained.

Just move the code that sets the checkbox checked status out of that `if`-`else` so that it is set for both new and recycled views.